# How can I check if element exists, close selenium driver if it does and if it doesn't continue with the script in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, element, exists

How can I check if the element exists, close driver if it does and if it doesn't continue with the script in Python

Something like

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('*****'));
close.driver()
```

Exactly what the title says.

Comment: Please provide some information about what you have tried and what went wrong so far. Also consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. We all start somewhere :)

Answer (score 1):

How about using 'try' and 'except' like this:

```
try: driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('*****'))
except: driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately this didn't work..... ah, should be driver.close()

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that part. Updated. Does it work now?

Comment: @juniper25 Could you please accept the answer if you are satisfied? I'm also new here, trying to build up reputation. Thank you